# Parsing a string to a Java method

Tags: java, for-loop, substring

I'm completely new to Java, so I'm sorry if the answer to this seems obvious...

I've written a method in my class as follows:

```
private static final String[] rCode = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"}

  private int getCharValue(String code)
  {
    // loop through the codes to find a
    // matching code, if found exit loop (via return).
    for (int position = 0; position < rCode.length; position++)
    {
      if (rCode[position] == code)
        return rVal[position];
    } // for

    // otherwise return 0
    return 0;
  } // getCharValue
```

In another method of the same class I am looping through the characters of a string as follows:

```
String number = "MMMCDXXXIV";

for (int pos = 0; pos < number.length(); pos++)
{ 
  System.out.println(number.substring(pos, pos + 1) + " " + getCharValue(number.substring(pos, pos + 1)));
} // for
```

My problem is that while my getCharValue() method works fine when I hardcode a value in, e.g. `getCharValue("X")` it does not work when I call it like `getCharValue(number.substring(pos, pos + 1))` (even though I know `number.substring(pos, pos + 1)` is returning single characters which should be returning values.

Can anyone see my obvious mistake?

Many thanks...

Comment: how does it not work? What results or error are you getting?

Comment: hi, what is rCode in your getCharValue function?

Comment: @evildead rCode is a static array, Fred posted this is a comment. I've edited it into the main answer. I assume `rVal` is also static somewhere.

Comment: Technically, `number.substring(pos, pos + 1)` returns a String which contains a single character. Don't confuse `char` with `String` :)

Comment: If rCode contains strings with several characters, please note that your code where you use substring will never pluck out strings that will match against them because you're always plucking out single-character strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (rCode[position] == code)
```

That does not do what you want in Java.  It's not comparing if the characters that make up the string are the same, it's comparing if they two String objects are actually the same object.  So it works when you compare two compile time literals, because the compiler is smart enough to point them to the same internal object.  However, when you generate new Strings at runtime, it will fail.

You want to do:

```
if (rCode[position].equals(code))
```

Answer (score 3):

One problem is using `==` to compare strings instead of `string1.equals(string2);`
`==` is to determine if the 2 are the same object, `.equals` checks to see if they have the same contents.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two Strings with `==` will compare the objects. Since Java caches String literals, it will appear to work when passing a String literal as you see when using getCharValue("X"). The correct approach is to use `rCode[position].equals(code);`. `equals()` compares the contents of the strings, which is what you want. You might also want `equalsIgnoresCase()` which ignores case when comparing strings.

I would, however, suggest changing your code to comparing characters instead. Change `getCharValue()` to take a `char` and then use `rCode.charAt(position)` to access an individual character from `rCode`. Also use `charAt` when calling the new `getCharValue()` instead of using `substring()`.

EDIT: What I said about using characters fails since learning that `rCode` contains strings with multiple characters. However, as mentioned in a comment above I see problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here, but if you're trying to check if you have a substring in your string, maybe you want to check the `.contains()` method:
[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Basically I have the two arrays such that:

private static final String[] rCode = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

and

private static final int[] rVal = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};

I want the getCharValue() method to return the corresponding rVal for a given rCode.. I know there are better ways of doing this but I need to do it using this method in order to meet the requirements of the task.